# What are the advantages of using a String Set rather than String in DynamoDB?

Tags: arrays, string, amazon-dynamodb

I been trying to look for it around the net and can't find a good answer for this. What are the advantages of using `SS` rather than `S`? Is it speed? Productivity? I am setting my DB and wanted to know before I get to much further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SS` is a Set of strings. You can use the `contains(my_string_set_attribute, :value)` condition expression to conditionally write to an item if the string set `SS` contains a particular value or not.

`S` is one string so it is a scalar attribute, not a collection. With strings, the `contains` expression function answers the question, "is the given value a substring of the attribute a at a given path?"